# aws hosted zone nslookup shows serverfails

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created hosted zone in aws and I added the nameservers to my domain

when I tried nslookup on the domain I am getting error

```
ubuntu@xx-xx-xx-xx:~$ nslookup --type=ns kims.oshabz.name.ng
*** Invalid option: -type=ns
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find kims.oshabz.name.ng: No answer
```

Comment: Why are you querying localhost (127.0.0.1) if you want to query an AWS DNS resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One dash not two before "type". Try this corrected command:

`nslookup -type=ns kims.oshabz.name.ng`

I was able to duplicate your error on Ubuntu 20.04 and this change resolved it.